# Система лайков на PHP и Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Лайки выполняются  на странице с определенным id.
Но на общей странице блоки лайков не работают.
id="like" должны быть классами, но не работает.

```js
$("#like").bind("click", function(event) {
  $.ajax({
    url: "",
    type: "POST",
    data: ("id=" + $("#like").attr("data-id")),
    dataType: "text",
    success: function(result) {
      if (result) {
        $("#like").text(Number($("#like").text()) + 1);
      } else alert("Error");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#like {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 20px;
}

​
```

```html
<?php
 $id = 1; // ID статьи выбирается из db
 if($_POST["id"]) echo $votes += 1; //увеличиваем количество лайков на 1 в блоке. 
?>
  ​
  <div id="like" data-id="<?=$id?>">
    <?=$votes?>
  </div>
  ​
```

```css
 .like{
 width:30px;
 height:30px;
 border:1px solid red;
 margin:20px;
 }
​
```

```html
Хотелось бы так на одной странице
<div class="like" data-id="<?=$id?>">
  <?=$votes?>
</div>
<div class="like" data-id="<?=$id?>">
  <?=$votes?>
</div>
<div class="like" data-id="<?=$id?>">
  <?=$votes?>
</div>​
```

Comment: в чём, собственно, проблема? У вас на общей странице, грубо говоря, есть массив id, вы через foreach их выводите и всё.

Comment: Так одновременно срабатывают все лайки. В базу вноситтся только первый. Если foreach в result, незнаю

Comment: добавил в ответ

Answer (score 1):

Для страницы со всеми лайками надо и менять всё у эл-та на котором ивент сработал

```
$(".like").bind("click", function(event) {
  $.ajax({
    url: "",
    type: "POST",
    data: ("id=" + event.target.dataset.id),
    dataType: "text",
    success: function(result) {
      if (result) {
        $(event.target).text(Number($(event.target).text()) + 1);
      } else alert("Error");
    }
  });
});
```